# I would like to select a point and find information about connecting vertices using Geometry Nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, vertices, procedural

In the appended image I have a vertex with 4 other vertices attached to it, is it possible to select the index of that vertex and find information such as how many edges are connected as well as the angle of those points relative to the initial "parent" point?

I am trying to make a procedural pipe generator that can dynamically add 90 degree turns as well as 3 or 4 way junction points in the pipes.

[image: image of vertices connected]